# Compare 2 differents array php

Tags: php, arrays, php-5.3

I have a question.
So I have the first array like this (aFirst):

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
        (
           [gift] => 3435353
        )
 [1] => Array
        (
            [gift] => 1234
        )
 )
```

And the second array (aSecond) :

```
Array
(
   [0] => Array
           (
              [gift_id] => 1234
           )
   [1] => Array
           (
              [gift_id] => 46545
           )
 )
```

Now I need to compare the values from array aSecond.gift_id whith all values from array aFirst.gift. I have no idea how to do that. Please help me. Thx in advance

Comment: Are you looking for `in_array();`  or you want to compare every single value and then do something with it ? , it depends also on what you want to achieve with comparing them

Comment: what you want as output?

Comment: And what have you tried?

Comment: If is the same I want to get the gift_id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this.. Haven't tested this though.

1. Loop through each value in `$aSecond`.
2. Compare each value to `$aFirst` using an `array_search`.

> The array_search() function search an array for a value and returns the key.

3. If a key is found, then the row on `$aSecond` exists on `$aFirst`.

.

```
foreach($aSecond as $row) {
    if(array_search($row['gift_id'], array_column($aFirst, 'gift')) !== false) {
        echo 'value is in multidim array';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this :

```
foreach ($aSecond as $key => $value) {
   if (in_array($value['gift_id'], $aFirst)) {
       echo 'GIFT ID : ' . $value['gift_id'] . ' in array aFirst';     
   }
}
```